Using awk in ksh script
I have a requirement to split a large CSV file using KSH script. I came across below link which is using AWK utility
Split CSV files into smaller files but keeping the headers?
I tried the same as below -
# Split file
awk -v l=${FILE_LINE_COUNT_LIMIT} '(NR==1){header=$0;next}
                                   (NR%l==2) {
                                   close(file);
                                   file=sprintf("%s.%0.5d.csv",FILENAME,++c)
                                   sub(/csv[.]/,"",file)
                                   print header > file
                                   }
                                   {print > file}' ${FTP_FILE}

but I get below error
awk: cmd. line:9: (FILENAME=test101001.csv FNR=2) fatal: expression for `>' redirection has null string value

not sure if it because the provided sample was BASH compatible but I am trying to do the same in KSH.
Please advise.

EDIT: Here's the above code indented legibly courtesy of GNU awk -o-:
(NR == 1) {
        header = $0
        next
}

(NR % l == 2) {
        close(file)
        file = sprintf("%s.%0.5d.csv", FILENAME, ++c)
        sub(/csv[.]/, "", file)
        print(header) > file
}

{
        print > file
}


Nothing to do with your shell, you're trying to write to file before it contains the name of a file. If you use normal indenting I expect it'll be easier for you to see the problem. Please also read correct-bash-and-shell-script-variable-capitalization and https://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes and run your shell scripts through http://shellcheck.net. Oh, and never name a variable l as it looks far too much like the number 1 and so obfuscates your code.

(Hint: think about what your code will do for each input line if l has the value 1 or 2). If you [edit] your question to show a [mcve] with concise, testable sample input and expected output then we can help you do whatever it is you're trying to do the right way.

Is FILE_LINE_COUNT_LIMIT defined somewhere?

awk doesn't care what shell it's executed from. And there's nothing in your script that depends on bash-specific features.

What part of this question is ksh-specific? I see absolutely nothing here that wouldn't be 100% identical with any other Bourne-family shell. The redirection that's failing is internal to awk itself, it isn't anything the shell plays any role in whatsoever.

The shortest change that fixes the immediate issue might to be to add to the top of your script BEGIN { file = "/dev/null" }

@CharlesDuffy unless l < 2, file is defined. so maybe better to assert l >= 2

As I mentioned in my comment, the error message you're getting has nothing to do with which shell you call your awk script from, just about how your awk script is written and the input you're providing it.
Without sample input/output it's just an untested guess but I THINK you probably want something like the following, using any awk:
awk -v tgtOutLines=10 '
    BEGIN {
        if ( tgtOutLines < 2 ) {
            print "do not do that" | "cat>&2"
            exit 1
        }
    }
    NR == 1 {
        hdr = $0
        base = FILENAME
        sub(/\.csv$/, "", base)
        next
    }
    (++numOutLines % tgtOutLines) == 1 {
        close(out)
        out = sprintf("%s.%0.5d.csv", base, ++numOutFiles)
        print hdr > out
        ++numOutLines
    }
    { print > out }
'

where tgtOutLines is how many lines you want per output file, including the header line.

@jhnc good point, done now, thanks.
